# Creating a chart with two date columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have some data from Google Analytics relating to traffic to one of my websites.

I would like to compare the traffic from now to the same time one year ago. However, to be difficult I do not simply want to compare by the date (ie. 1st Sept 2010 vs 1st Sept 2011). The reason being, the website traffic often drops on the weekend. Comparing simply by the date  means that I end up with a weekend day being compared against a weekday (Sunday vs Monday, due to the shift in days).

To give a better graph, I would like to compare by day of the week, so **Wed** 1st Sept **2010** is compared to **Wed** 31st Aug **2011**

At the moment I have two tables, one with the dates and traffic visits for the 2010 year, and another with the same data but for 2011.

Could someone advise on getting this into a graph, I've tried by creating one chart then adding another series but it only allows for one X axis so I have to choose either the 2010 or 2011 dates. I essentially need a second X axis. I tried swapping and having two Y axis but this really didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, unlike the Y axes, Excel doesn't allow for the creation of a secondary X axis.

I think if I were in your shoes, I'd just reposition the data to which the chart is referencing so that you match up the days as you want.